# Scope in angular directive not binding well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Good afternoon

I'm a newbie in angular ,and directives, and something with the scope it's not running ok ( in my case, of course :)).

I have defined the following directive :

```
angular.module('ToolBarMod', ['ngAria'])
.controller('ToolBarCtrl', [function ($scope) {}])
.directive('svdToolBar', function ($translate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            id: '@id',
            name: '@name',
            labelHeader: '@labelHeader',
            tooltipLabelSave: '@tooltipLabelSave',
            enableSave: '@enableSave',
            onClickSave: '&onClickSave',
            onChange: '&onChange'
        },
        template: '<div id="{{name}}" class="md-toolbar-tools">' +
                      '<md-toolbar md-scroll-shrink>' +
                            '<div class="md-toolbar-tools titulo margin-8">'+
                                '{{labelHeader}}' +
                                '<md-button id="save" class="tool toolBarButton" ng-disabled="{{enableSave}}" aria-label="{{ \'GEN-SAVE\' | translate }}" ng-click="onClickSave">' +
                                    '<md-tooltip>'+'{{tooltipLabelSave}}'+'</md-tooltip>' +
                                    '<ng-md-icon icon="save"></ng-md-icon>'+
                                '</md-button>'+
                            '</div>' +
                      '</md-toolbar>' +
                      '<div flex></div>' +
                    '</div>'
        }
});
```

})();

and the my html uses the directive this way

```
<svd-tool-bar id="toolbar" labelHeader="tasacion" name="toolbar" tooltipLabelSave="{{ 'VAL-NEW-I-N' | translate }}" enableSave="true"/>
```

in case of the attribute 'labelHeader' , there's something I'm not doing right . So , when the html it's loaded , I can't see the attribute 'tasacion' . The element 'labelHeader' it's empty .

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use `label-header` in the attribute

```
<svd-tool-bar id="toolbar" label-header="tasacion"
```

Comment: Wow ... thanks . I was looking for a more complex answer . Really thanks . Works great

Answer (score 2):

Angular expects the attribute names to be separated by '-' (just like the directive name).

So instead of `labelHeader` use `label-header` etc.

Comment: Works great . Thanks